# how to display result of two out parameters from procedure

Tags: out-parameters

Everything is OK if I have one out parameter in stored procedure. Now I would like to output two of them. Could you help me? What is wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(p_product_id IN products.product_id%TYPE, 
p_name OUT products.name%TYPE, p_description OUT products.description%TYPE)
AS BEGIN
SELECT PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.DESCRIPTION INTO p_name, p_description FROM 
PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTS.product_id = p_product_id;
END;
```

I would like to call this procedure and get output result of p_name and p_description.

```
DECLARE
 nazwa VARCHAR2(30),
 opis  VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
PROC1(1, nazwa, opis);
dbms_output.put_line(nazwa);
dbms_output.put_line(opis);
END;
```

I got an error.
"Rrror report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 19:
PLS-00103: Encountered "," expected:
   := ; not null default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error."

Answer (score 0):

nazwa VARCHAR2(30),
 opis  VARCHAR2(50);

you can see the  line 2 error
go to line 2 you see nazwa VARCHAR2(30)**,** it should be
nazwa VARCHAR2(30)**;**

Comment: Right, I got used to T-SQL, that's why I made the mistake. On the other hand, the error is very clear.